# Activating the workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a string "sFile" that stores the name of workbook with extension.

I want to activate this workbook, stored in a string.

And then close it.

Code am using is:

```
Dim wbk as workbook
Set wbk = Workbooks(sFile)
wbk.Activate
wbk.close
```

But this is not working.Please help.

Comment: The workbooks() approach doesn't use the extension, just the workbook name. Either use the name or cut the extension out of the string with Replace(). Edit: using extension works also but isn't mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to see if you succeed to `Set wbk = Workbooks(sFile)`, it wil work only if the workbook is open.

If it doesn't succeed (`wbk Is Nothing`), then you need to open the workbook.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub SetWB_toOpenWorkbook()

Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim sFile As String
Dim FilePath As String

' just an example of my file name (clean with extension)
sFile = "SO_1.xlsm"

' set the Dektop path
FilePath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\Desktop\"

On Error Resume Next
Set wbk = Workbooks(sFile)
On Error GoTo 0
If wbk Is Nothing Then ' if not open, then open the workbook
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & sFile)
End If

' just for my tests, put the workbook name in "A1" in "Sheet1"
wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = wbk.Name

wbk.Activate
wbk.Close True

End Sub
```

Comment: A clear process with good error capture! However given the objective within the question is to close the workbook doesn't it seem redundant to go through these steps?

Comment: @Zerk most likely, but I ususaly try to give answers as if I would have to use this code (most times it's oveerkill)

Comment: I modified it in my code only in 3-4 lines.It worked. Thanks a lot Shai :)

Comment: @DivyaRoopam you're welcome, thanks for marking as "ANSWER"

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, it only takes the name (not path) - this should do it for you:

```
Dim wbk as workbook
Set wbk = Workbooks(right(sFile,Instrrev(sFile,"\")+1))
wbk.Activate
wbk.close
```